# PowerShell corrupted with Exception code: 0xc0000409

Tags: powershell

I write a script calles `test_01.ps1` and try the following command:

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy remotesigned C:Temp\\psScript\\test_01.ps1
```

in cmd.

PowerShell always corrupted with the following Event log:

```
Faulting application name: powershell.exe, version: 10.0.19041.546, time stamp: 0x7eda4115
Faulting module name: webio.dll, version: 10.0.19041.1620, time stamp: 0x99fecee7
Exception code: 0xc0000409
Fault offset: 0x0000000000064558
Faulting process id: 0x20f4
Faulting application start time: 0x01d8ae142612cddd
Faulting application path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\webio.dll
Report Id: 10a79226-9ef5-491a-938e-ba80aebc70d9
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

`test_01.ps1` details:

```
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "5up" -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential("root",$password)
invoke-command -computername "192.168.2.254" -credential $cred -scriptblock { ping.exe 192.168.2.1 -n 15 -l 32 }
```

Comment: I don't quite understand - are you starting three separate instances of PowerShell within your script? Each line in your script starts with `powershell.exe`?

Comment: Sorry for that. Already correct the test_01.ps1

Comment: Have you tried running [fsc /scannow](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-correct-common-user32-dll-file-errors-3b34cc67-5741-ce2b-cc7d-86d5410f44f4) already?

Comment: FWIW `0xc0000409` is `STATUS_STACK_BUFFER_OVERRUN`. This is not an error one would expect on a properly working installation, nor does it seem specific to PowerShell, since the faulting module isn't part of PowerShell itself. You may end up needing to reinstall Windows and/or scan the system for possible malware (including poorly behaving third party software that DLL injects itself into things and works bad enough to be indistinguishable from malware -- ironically, that not seldom means malware scanners themselves).

Comment: @Theo
Yes, already tried "sfc /scannow"

Comment: I reimaged the computer, unfortunately,  this issue still exists.